# How to user Netgear switch FMS726s

Tags: cli

I just joined to a new company and they are using Netgear Switch FMS726s. I never used Netgear switches and their CLI. They have CLI and kinda similar to Cisco but I can't go back to edit my typo error. Everytime I use Delete (backspace); it won't go back but it spaces. I use Mac, but not sure it will do any differences. Any advices?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know the right answer but here is a thread that may help. http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040930002324870

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out, I have to hit CTRL+H to do backspace (delete). How's weird..Anyways Thanks for helping

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. By the way, <CTRL>+H has been a backspace since ASCII was defined, decades ago. It is different than a delete.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a bash or Unix or Linux environment.

type bash or just type

```
stty erase <press backspace key>
```